# Android Studio: Select min sdk version not working?

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to select min sdk version to 11. After I finish creating the project, the main activity still shows I am importing v7 ActionBarActivity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
...
```

Did I configure something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Sync your `Gradle` changes by re-importing the `Gradle` files and then clean and rebuild the project if necessary.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more detail? I am new to Android development and not sure if I understand what it means. Thanks

Comment: What version of Android Studio is this? There have been fixes made to the templates that drive the new project wizard, though those fixes aren't real recent.

Answer (score 0):

- Open your `build.gradle` file and make sure that `minSdkVersion` is set to 11.
- Click the Sync Gradle Files button on the toolbar to the left of the SDK manager

  - the Gradle files will now be automatically re-imported
- Clean and Rebuild your project

Comment: Resyncing your project in most cases isn't going to change Java include statements.

Comment: Correct, I'm assuming that while coding, the current import statements were the ones recognized by android studio as importable.  So by resyncing the project, android studio may now recognize the appropriate import statements, in which case the current import statement can be replaced as appropriate.

Comment: I was thinking it might be some bug where the new project wizard includes support library even if you set your minSDK such that it shouldn't need it. Note that his code is referencing ActionBarActivity, which is a support lib class. I can't reproduce the bug in Studio 0.5.2 though.

Comment: Hmmm, I see what you're saying.  If I'm not mistaken, the support library that is being included should be listed in the `build.gradle` file as a dependency.

Comment: I don't see an actual build/IDE error in the question; it just seems to be questioning why it's using the v7 support lib stuff.

Comment: If it were me, I would have a hard time imagining that I might accidentally add a support library as a dependency, which is why I suspect it's an IDE issue - though you raise a good point.  As far as I'm aware, Android Studio will add dependencies that coorespond to those included in `build.gradle`, so if the v7 support lib _somehow_ was added as a dependency in that file, it would explain the issue.

Comment: I am using 0.4.2. Is there a 0.5.2? I cannot find in from the official website.

Comment: Hmm, I updated it to 0.5.2. It looks better (at least the v7 ActionBar and v4 Fragment go away) but it still have the v7 ActionBarActivity and my MainActiviy is still extending it after I select Android version 11.

Answer (score 0):

For those using Android Studio 0.8.6 and having the same issue while following Google's tutorials, what worked for me was to add this line under "dependecies" in your module build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
}
```

it worked for me!

:)

Answer (score 0):

No, android studio import it automatically because there are some features that worked since version 14.

For example: when you set the `actionbar` in your XML document and you want to hide / show some item you use `"android:showAsAction"` attribute, but the compiler generates an error, because that works only on version 14 and later.

So, the compiler tells you that you have to change it in `"yourapp:showAsAction"` (because you declared to support version 11) where "yourapp" is a namespace that you've imported in your `xml` file:

```
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto
```

Remember that "yourapp" can be every name you want! Well, now if you test your app you find out that show / hide functionality doesn't work properly, and this is because your activity doesn't extends `ActionBarActivity`. This is why androidStudio automatically extends `ActionBarActivity` when you declare a minSdk of 11.

Hope this post was useful, bye!